# GIven a level order FInd BST

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

Given a BST whose level-order traversal is:

```
99 65 53 80 22 62 98 21 49 82 36 51
```

what will be the tree if we make tree from the following level order traversal?

Comment: The way to do this is to start with the first, at the top, and for each new number you have to attach it to one on the previous line, or you have to continue on the same line. For each number thus make a decision, same line, or next line? And if next line, where to assign it that would make sense according to it being a BST.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I arrived at the BST I will present at the bottom.

The main governing rule is the one that has to apply to a BST: If you were to "order" the elements, every node in the left subtree of a node has to be considered "before" the node, and every node in the right subtree has to be considered "after" the node.

Since you list numbers, and say nothing more about the rules for ordering, a simply numerical ordering is assumed.

As such, when placing the nodes we have to carefully find the correct location of each node given the following procedure:

1. Decide if we can find a place for it on the current level (if there is room for more nodes there). To find this we find all the places we could place it if we didn't care about the BST rule. Then check each such position to see if it is a legal position. There should be only one.
2. If we find such a place, place it there, if not, go to the next level and place it in its leftmost legal position there.
3. When placing more nodes on an existing level, we go from left to right.

So here's the runthrough of the given numbers:

1. The first level contains only one number, so this will be 99.
2. The second level can contain 1 or 2 numbers, so 65 has to be here but perhaps 53 does not. Since 65 is less than 99 it has to be placed down-left from 99. Can 53 be placed down-right from 99? No, so it has to be on the third level.
3. So 53 is on the third level, and it has to be down-left from 65.
4. What about 80? It will either be on the third level, down-right from 65, or on the fourth line. Can it be on the fourth line? It would either have to be less than 53, or greater than 53 and smaller than 65. It is greater than 65 so it cannot be on the fourth level so it too has to be on the third, down-right from 65.
5. Next comes 22, and it is less than 65, since we're now starting level 4 it is easy to place, it has to be placed down-right from 53.
6. Next up, 62, since it is still within the range of what the level above can have under it, we just have to find the right place for it. Since it is greater than 53, but not greater than 65, it has to be placed down-right from 53.
7. 98 is greater than 80. Since it is still less than 99, it still has a place in this main left subtree of 99 so we place it down-right from 80.
8. 21 is down-left from 22.
9. 49 is less than 53, but greater than 22, so it is placed down-right from 22.
10. 82 has to either be placed down-left or down-right from 62, down-left or down-right from 98, or start a new line. The only legal position for it in this line is down-left from 98.
11. 36 is greater than 21, but not greater than 49, so it has to be placed either down-right from 21 or down-left from 49. Since 36 is also greater than 22, it has to be down-left from 49.
12. The final number 51 is greater than 51, but not greater than 53, so it has to be placed somewhere in the left subtree of 53, and we place it down-right from 49.

Final BST:

```
            99
           /
         65
        /  \
      53    80
     /  \     \
   22    62    98
  /  \        /
21    49    82
     /  \
   36    51
```